# SwiftUI Can't Capture Image of MapView

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I have a SwiftUI app that includes a map. I want to capture an image of the map and display that image as a SwiftUI Image on another view. I have been unable to find any documentation on this. I tried two approaches at capturing and neither of them work. See the extensions below.

This is a simplified example:

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showDetail: Bool = false
    @State private var thumbImage: Image = Image(systemName: "gear")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is the ContentView")

            if showDetail {
                DetailMapView(thumbImage: $thumbImage)
            }

            if !showDetail {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.showDetail.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Tap for Map")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the MapView:

```
struct DetailMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MKMapView

    @Binding var thumbImage: Image

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: DetailMapView

        init(_ parent: DetailMapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }//coordinator

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        // this does not work - it crashes  
        // let s = mapView.pb_takeSnapshot()
        // self.thumbImage = Image(uiImage: s)

        //this does not work either - it produces lots of console complaints
        let t = mapView.screenshot
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.thumbImage = Image(uiImage: t)
        }

        return mapView
    }
}

extension UIView {

    func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}

extension UIView {

    var screenshot: UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return UIImage() }
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        guard let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return UIImage() };
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenShot
    }
}
```

Console output for the screenshot version:

```
[VKDefault] TextureAtlasPage: Atlas page destroyed with outstanding references.: Assertion with expression - _textureRefs == 0 : Failed in file - /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1606.34.10.29.27/src/TextureAtlas.cpp line - 604
[VKDefault] TextureAtlasPage: Atlas page destroyed with outstanding references.: Assertion with expression - _textureRefs == 0 : Failed in file - /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1606.34.10.29.27/src/TextureAtlas.cpp line - 604
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 11.4 (11E146)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others:
This works for me - forget the extensions above. The key is to use 
mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap and that function needs to be inside the Coordinator class.

```
func mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView, fullyRendered: Bool) {

    //setup whatever region you want to see :mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: mapView.bounds.size)
    let ratio = mapView.bounds.size.height / mapView.bounds.size.width
    let img = render.image { (ctx) in
        mapView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300 * ratio), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.parent.thumbImage = Image(uiImage: img)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , what about MapKit in SwiftUI 2.0 ? is there a way to capture image from it ? or 
I should use MapKit from UIKit ?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use MKMapSnapshotter from Apple because if you render the map manually yourself you always get the Apple symbol with it...which you "normally" do not want ;)